# Fish + Virtualenvs: Wrong "which pip" location but correct pip install location

Tags: pip, virtualenv, fish

I am experiencing unexpected/unusable behavior from pip and virtualenvs. For context, I am using fish shell.

When I create a new virtual env and install new packages to it, pip list/freeze correctly shows the installed packages. However, which pip routes to my system python, not my virtual environment python. 
Before and after entering my virtualenv, which pip returns the same system path. Further, when I run code, my import statements do not detect installed packages.

I've spent days looking through over posts before asking, but I haven't found one that describes my exact situation / an adequate solution.

It is not a problem due to:
- aliases

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `type pip` show? `which` is an external tool.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to activate your virtual environment?

Comment: @glennjackman type pip outputs:
pip is /$USER/miniconda3/bin/pip

Comment: @JustinMayer command:
 source *myenv*/bin/activate.fish

Comment: And, is that the pathname you expect to see? Is that different from what `which pip` shows you?

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry, I am using pip3.    
which pip3:
>> /usr/local/bin/pip3   
type pip3:
>> pip3 is /usr/local/bin/pip3    My virtual environment path is 
/$USER/Documents/Student:Professional General/Coding_Database/Machine Learning Examples/general_ml_venv

Comment: I'm new to posting on stackoverflow so I'm unsure of how to linebreak in my comments. I apologize if my comment is hard to read.

Comment: As I think you already understand, the output of `type pip3` / `which pip3` — when run inside an activated virtualenv — should show `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/pip3` and not `/usr/local/bin/pip3`. So it seems something is awry with virtualenv activation / `$PATH` manipulation.

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to create the virtual environment?

Comment: @JustinMayer while in my project directory, source *myenv*/bin/activate.fish. Is there a way I can edit $PATH to route correctly?

Comment: What is the exact command you are using to **create** the virtual environment? (not **activate**)

Comment: @JustinMayer sorry about that; python3 -m venv *env_name*

Comment: If you look at the contents of `activate.fish` you'll see that it should adjust your PATH via: `set -gx PATH "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin" $PATH`  After activating your virtual environment, what do you see when you run: `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: @JustinMayer
/$USER/Documents/Student Professional General/Coding_Database/Machine Learning Examples/general_ml_venv/bin $USER/miniconda3/bin miniconda3/bin /$USER/miniconda3/bin/ /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin /Library/TeX/texbin . /miniconda3/bin /miniconda3/condabin /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin /$USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin /$USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2@global/bin /$USER/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin /$USER/miniconda3/bin /$USER/.rvm/bin

Comment: Your virtualenv bin path is listed first, so that looks right. Perhaps the spaces in that path are at fault? What happens if you create a new virtualenv, say, at `/$USER/Virtualenvs/general_ml`, install your Python dependencies into it, and run your code? Do your imports work properly then? Does `type pip3` / `which pip3` return the path to your virtualenv (and not `/usr/local/bin/pip3`)?

Comment: @JustinMayer Imports do not work propertly. which / type still return /usr/local/bin/pip3 for a new virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

[Virtualfish](https://github.com/excitedleigh/virtualfish) is a project designed to gracefully handle virtual environments in a Fish shell context. You may find it provides a solution to the problems you are experiencing, as well as a number of other significant benefits.